# Failed to pull image with policy "always": Error response from daemon

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, dockerhub

I am facing Failed to pull image with policy "always": Error response from daemon:Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/docker/manifests/20.10.17-dind: unauthorized: incorrect username or password (manager.go:203:0s) error while trying to run my pipeline to push my code on docker hub.

I tried different solution but everytime I get same error. I am using username of my dockerhub rather than email but facing same issue. One of my friend told me it may be dind issue you have to mentioned docker and dind image and service latest version tags but still same issue. Please help me, I really appriciate your efforts in advance.
Please check code screenshot attached with it.

Comment: Please check if this helps: https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/1689

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check if this is an authentication issue similar to [this one](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/28981#note_903816992)

> We noticed that the job succeeds if we delete Docker config file `~/.docker/config.json`, containing credentials from previous CI jobs.
>
> That is the reason why you should always use `docker logout <registry>` if the job runs in a non-disposable environment